# Javascript Each input/element with div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, each

I am currently developing a dynamic form where when a user selects an item from a select list different data is added to the form based on that selection. These new elements get laced within a Div with an ID of "**dyn**", so basically I tried the code below to get the id's of the newly added fields and write them to the console:

```
$("#dynObject").change(function() {

                 alert('Inside Change Function');

                 $("#dyn > input").each(function() {
                  console.log( $(this).attr("id") );
                });

            });
```

The alert for this code is displayed however none of the id's are sent to the console. Each of dynamic elements will have an id containing the string "**DynField**" so I don’t know if I can do a each where id contains that value?

Hope someone can help me with this issue :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved my issue and thought I would share the details. I simple used the code below to target the Div with the fields and then iterate through each of the elements within it:

```
$("#dyn :input").each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).attr("value") );
});
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

To get all input elements that have an `id` which contains the string `DynField` you can use

```
input[id*="DynField"];
```

So in your example it would be

```
$('input[id*="DynField"]').each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this and it does partly work, however probably should have said that some fields are Inputs and others are Selects, I did presume it would treat the Selects the same as Inputs but doesn't seem to. Any idea's?